# WordPress Initial HTTP request (of viewport) takes forever

Tags: php, wordpress, server, wordpress-theming

I am managing a WP commerce (with Woocommerce) website.

For some reason, in some pages, the first HTTP request takes a really long time to load and the server experiences very high CPU usage:

[The HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sSZH.png)

I tried using various performance monitors to analyze the situation, there was a relatively big amount of queries but it does not seem to be the main cause:

[query monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO07q.png)

I tried to change a theme in order to isolate the problem and there was a major improvement.

Also, there are no apparent PHP errors and I checked the plugins.

My question is: how and if I can try and solve it without changing all of the theme? And is there anything else I have missed here?

Comment: Where are you hosting your site? Also, what did you do to check plugins?  I'd recommend disabling all plugins and switching to one of the default themes.  This should let you know if the problem is in your codebase or having to do with your host.

Comment: I am hosting at a good managed hosting. but while switching my plugins on and off I found that the redux part of my theme was slowing it down as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906877/wordpress-legatus-theme-slow-loading  . also while monitoring the requested resources I found some malware that should be dealt with, thanks for the response.